# A closed form of a integral with exp and cos

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Can we find a closed form for the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} \cos x}{1+x} \, {\rm d}x$$

No matter how hard I tried I cannot tackle it. I am pretty much afraid that if a closed form exists then it will involve hypergeometric functions. If that is the case, then I am not so interested in finding the closed form.

Comment: Mathematica answers in terms of the [MeijerG-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function), and I would not say that is a good sign...

Comment: @mickep. What is interesting is that the antiderivative looks "much more pleasant" ! But, as you said, your result does not look very appealing. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh! So the primitive is expressed in terms of Exponential integrals. Maybe that is more in the taste of OP?

Comment: @mickep Sure, if we can express it in terms of Exponential integrals no problem. That is much more of my taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} \cos \left( x \right)}{1+x}  = Re \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} e^{ix}}{1+x}$$
Now, substitute $x \rightarrow x-1$ and then $x \rightarrow \frac{x}{i-1}$ now and use the fact that
$$ Ei \left( x \right) = -\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Thanks .. That is much more of my taste.